# How to rotate a gameobject to the specific angle

Tags: c#, unity, rotation

I have tree model that is being rotating .After certain angle it should stop rotating.I have done a sample code.But the tree is not stopping.

```
void Update () {

        //transform.Rotate (0f,0,0.5f*Time.deltaTime);
        //transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward,Time.deltaTime*5);
    transform.Rotate (0f,0f,time);
    Debug.Log(time);
    time+=0.5f;
   if(time==5.5f)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles=Vector3.zero;
    }
```

}

From the above code I need to stop the rotation when the z axis value is 5.5f.How can I do this . Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing: `if (time == 5.5f)`, you need to do: `if (time >= 5.5f)`.

The rotation is stopping for a short amount of time (One update), but then the time variable is increased the next update. Its not equal to 5.5 anymore, so the rotation continues.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `==` with floats as sometimes can be problem if the number cannot be represent exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, once it reaches 5.5f indeed the rotation vector should be zero, but this is `Update()` we're talking about. If we take what you have written outside of the if statement :

```
transform.Rotate (0f,0f,time);
Debug.Log(time);
time+=0.5f;
```

On every frame, your object will rotate by 0.5 eulerAngle, then 1, then 1.5, infinitely. To fix this you can just make a bigger if statement like this :

```
time+=0.5f;
 if(time!=5.5f) {
transform.Rotate (0f,0f,time);
 }
 else
{
    transform.eulerAngles=Vector3.zero;
}
```

This should logically work.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update () {
    //if you are past the amount of degrees, then you don't need to rotate more.
    if (this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z > /*amount of degrees*/ 5.5f) return;

    //rotate more
    this.transform.Rotate (0, 0, 0.1f);
}
```

Or better, I would make a quaternion of the starting angle and the end angle ( using: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html ), then I would lerp ( using: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html ) between the two values.

Hope that helps!